# Postgresql to_char() function for all results from a query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

So I have been doing some work with postgreSQL and dealing with formatting the dates that I receive as an output from a simple query.

To run my query and return my list of dates I simply call something like:

```
select date from tablename;
```

This works well, and returns back to me a large list of dates in a format that is slightly off from my desired output.

Then after doing some research I discovered the function `TO_CHAR()`. This I had some success with again - I was able to call the function like so:
`select to_char(NOW(), 'Month dd, YYYY');`

My question and where I have gotten stuck with some errors is how I might be able to pass in the results from the initial query into the to_char() function.

Apologies if this is a relatively basic question (I am a beginner when it comes to postgresql).

Comment: Can you add your original query to the question?

Comment: For client privacy reasons I would prefer not to. Hope you understand and that my intention with the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as the following:

```
select to_char(tablename.date, 'Month dd, YYYY') from tablename;
```